# Insert submatrix with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to achieve the following R example with `Rcpp`:

```
X <- matrix(0, 5, 10)
X[1:4, 4] <- rexp(4)
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix foo1() {
  NumericMatrix X(5, 10);
  NumericMatrix y(4, 1);
  y(_, 0) = rexp(4, 1);
  X(Range(0,3),Range(3,3)) = y;
  return X; 
}
```

But I keep getting a compilation error, saying that `no match for 'operator='`. Any hints to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you have to pass by y

Comment: Have you checked out [`RcppArmadillo`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/index.html)? Assignment to submatrices is very easy using Armadillo ([docs link](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matrix operations with Rcpp are a bit lacking for better or worse.
Any in-depth matrix work should be done with either [RcppArmadillo](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) or [RcppEigen](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RcppEigen).

Sample implementation:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat matrix_fill_single_col() {

  // Setup X matrix
  arma::mat X = arma::zeros<arma::mat>(5, 10);

  // Generate random values from exponential and save into a vector.
  arma::vec y = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(Rcpp::rexp(4, 1));

  // Fill the fourth column in X (Recall: C++ indexes start at 0 not 1)
  X.submat(0, 3, 3, 3) = y;
  // Or...
  // X.col(3) = y;

  return X; 
}
```

Test

```
matrix_fill_single_col()
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]      [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    0    0 0.2685970    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [2,]    0    0    0 1.6018346    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [3,]    0    0    0 0.6467853    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [4,]    0    0    0 0.6655340    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [5,]    0    0    0 0.0000000    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Comment: "for better or worse": That comment misunderstands purpose.  Rcpp is not a "matrix math" library but first and foremost glue.  There is no point in duplicating Armadillo (or Eigen) as they do what they do, and as the post shows, "the glue" gets us there as is.  Division of labor, finite resources, and all that.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel agreed. I suppose why I added that disclaimer is that there are certain operations present that then cause future expectations to be violated (e.g. subsetting but no ability to insert a subset matrix into another.)

Comment: It is also arguably confusing: "Yo you guys have a matrix class and it can't add matrices."  But there's a reason, and there's also always another fire to extinguish.